# Finding out what deletes files (folder monitoring) in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm using Nexus 5 and have some files on "internal storage" in custom folders... After a while this files gets deleted not by me...

Is there any procedure or application which would monitor the folder and logged who (user or process) accessed file and who deleted it?

Best regards,

Pohorc

Comment: Where specifically on internal storage are you storing these files? `getFilesDir()`? `getCacheDir()`? Someplace else? `FileObserver` can tell you when changes occur, but not who makes them.

Comment: I think you have them in external memory. I suppose your phone is not rooted. Then other apps cannot interfere with files in the app specific internal memory.